# Laravel 8 Inertia HighCharts not being imported in the app.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, highcharts, inertiajs

I am trying to integrate Highcharts with app.js in Laravel 8 with Vue and Inertia. I am trying to figure out how to pass HighchartsVue. I am trying to pass it to the use function for the createApp. However, I can't access it in the templates.

### App.js

```
require("./bootstrap");

// Import modules...
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import HighCharts from ""
import {
    App as InertiaApp,
    plugin as InertiaPlugin,
} from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";

const el = document.getElementById("app");

createApp({
    render: () =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
        }),
})
    .mixin({ methods: { route } })
    .use(InertiaPlugin)
    .mount(el);
```

My template that tries to access the Vue Template. I haven't included the entire template here.

### Vue Template

```
<div>
    <highcharts :options="indexOptions"></highcharts>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a **global** registration:

After you have installed "highcharts-vue" using:

`npm install highcharts-vue`

Register it globally as a plugin in your `app.js` with:

`import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue'`

Next register it as a plugin in your vue object with:

`Vue.use(HighchartsVue)`

Please see the documentation [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue%5D) for more detailed instructions (and how to register it locally in the component).

After installing, your `app.js` would look something like this:

```
require("./bootstrap");

// Import modules...
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue'
import {
    App as InertiaApp,
    plugin as InertiaPlugin,
} from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";

Vue.use(HighchartsVue);

const el = document.getElementById("app");

createApp({
    render: () =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
        }),
})
    .mixin({ methods: { route } })
    .use(InertiaPlugin)
    .mount(el);
```